# Selecting bands of image collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to use the Landsat 8 surface reflection collection (LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR), which contains the 7 spectral bands plus some extra mask bands. I want to run my algorithm on just the 7 spectral bands, but I'm not sure how to select these. Does the `ee.ImageCollection` object have a method which allows you to specify which bands are used?

I am trying to run the `ee.Algorithms.Landsat.SimpleComposite` method on the image collection, which will not run if there is a mask band in the images.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`imageCollection.select([old bands], [new band names])` creates a new image collection containing only a specified set of bands from the images in a specified image collection

```js
var bandSubset = origCol.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'], ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'])
```

Comment: Note that `.select()` is a method of both `ee.ImageCollection` and `ee.Image` objects. Additionally, the "new band names" parameter is optional - if unspecified, the original band names are used.